# invalid argument '-mmacosx-version-min=10.12' not allowed with '-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

I am building llvm-3.4 with clang in Mac OS 10.12, but after I successfully configure it with

```
cmake-3.8.0(LLVM_ENABLE_PIC=FALSE,LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM;Mips;X86,CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/my/install/path/)
```

I build the program with Xcode 9.0, but I get this error message:

> clang: error:invalid argument '-mmacosx-version-min=10.12' not allowed
>   with '-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0' clang: warning:Using sysroot
>   for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX'

It seems that this is not a severe problem, but I just don't know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: @Geshode, excuse me, but the question is clear. Which information are you missing to give an answer?

Comment: Could you check deployment target and base SDK in Xcode project settings?

Comment: Thanks! my BaseSDK in build settings is macOS10.13 what other things may i miss?